# how transfer image file from server to another server by asp.net3.5

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

i host my website on server and my database on another server ,i connect to db by webservices and in need to upload image files to database server how i can do it by asp.net 3.5 and jquery

i have oracle database ,and i need to save image in table ,i have asp.net on source server but server which has db hasnt asp ,and i can make ftp share file on db sever but i need another way

Comment: What is the database? Do you want to save the image in table ?

Comment: can you run asp.net on both servers ? In the server that you like to upload the image if you do not have asp.net, do you have ftp access that you can use ?

Comment: database is oracle ,and i need save image in table

Answer (score 1):

If it's server to server then you shouldn't need to use jQuery.

You will need a windows service or IIS hosted WCF service running on your target database server.  This service will expose a WCF endpoint and have a connection to the database.  Then you'll need to write a client on your source server that either takes file names as input or monitors the file system, this will connect to the WCF service on your database server.

A better way to architect this would be to connect directly to the database from the source server and pass the data into a table row with a column type for data.

Comment: thanks adrian, i am not know wcf can you give me simple example ,thanks alot

Comment: There's an example at the following link, it has a link at the bottom where you can download some WCF Examples.  It might be worth downloading these samples and looking at the code for the Streaming example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751463.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can transfer files from one server to another server via ftpclient using asp.net.

Sample code will be like this.

```
FtpWebRequest ftpClient = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(ftpurl + "_" + filename);
ftpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(ftpusername, ftppassword);
ftpClient.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
ftpClient.UseBinary = true;
ftpClient.KeepAlive = true;
System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(fileurl);
ftpClient.ContentLength = fi.Length;
byte[] buffer = new byte[4097];
int bytes = 0;
int total_bytes = (int)fi.Length;
System.IO.FileStream fs = fi.OpenRead();
System.IO.Stream rs = ftpClient.GetRequestStream();
while (total_bytes > 0)
{
   bytes = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
   rs.Write(buffer, 0, bytes);
   total_bytes = total_bytes - bytes;
}
fs.Close();
rs.Close();
FtpWebResponse uploadResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpClient.GetResponse();
string status = uploadResponse.StatusDescription;
uploadResponse.Close();
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks my brother Muhammad Irfan this way need ftp file share on database server ,can i uplade file from client to db server directly without pass by source server